# Trouble with integer type in python

Tags: python

I have a problem converting from float type to integer:

```
a=0.0003
b=a*10000
c=int(b)
```

This code returns me 2 but i need 3. And`b-3.0` returns this

```
>>> b-3.0
```

-4.44089209850063e-16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the effect of floating point representation and the fact that `int` truncates the fractional part of a floating point number.

The former leads to `a*10000` evaluating to a number slightly less than `3`.

The latter such a number evaluates to `2` when converted to `int`:

```
>>> print int(2.999999999999)
2
```

You could fix this by rounding the result of the floating point multiplication:

```
b = round(a * 10000)
c = int(b)
```

Here, `b` has the value `3.0` and `int(b)` evaluates to `3`.

Comment: I guess, this is the best way to solve my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
In [27]: a = 0.0003
In [29]: a*10000
Out[29]: 2.9999999999999996
In [30]: int(a*10000)
Out[30]: 2
In [31]: b =a*10000
In [32]: b
Out[32]: 2.9999999999999996
In [33]: print b
3.0
In [34]: c = int(b)
In [35]: c
Out[35]: 2
In [37]: b - 3.0
Out[37]: -4.440892098500626e-16
```

As you can see `a* 10000` retursns `2.999....96` and python makes it 2   on using `int(b)`. This is expected behaviour. For what you want I would suggest usint `floor` and `ceil` functions in `math` module:

```
In [38]: import math
In [41]: math.ceil(b)
Out[41]: 3.0
In [42]: math.floor(b)
Out[42]: 2.0
In [43]: math.floor(b-3.0)
Out[43]: -1.0
In [44]: math.ceil(b-3.0)
Out[44]: -0.0
```